# How to find what properties exposed to configuration files?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

I think I don't understand the basics of how configurations works. Let's take for example [SimpleMailWebEventProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.simplemailwebeventprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Just by looking at MSDN documentation, how would I find out what is configurable in  web config? In the example  there's many configurable properties, such as "to", "subject prefix". These properties are not public and, other than in the examples, there's no information on what can be set in web.config. There's no intelli-sense either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a link at the bottom of the MSDN to [HealthMonitoring Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.healthmonitoringsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Normally, if this was well documented, this page would contain what you need, or at least link to what you need.  Unfortunately though, you seem to have hit on some poor documentation.

I was able to find some more details on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650305.aspx#paght000011_moreinfo.  This appears to be the extent of the documentation for that element on MSDN.